# Debugging csv read in c

Tags: c, csv, debugging

I'm having some trouble with a project I'm working on for my master thesis. I got some help from a user here a while back, but the code doesn't quite seem to be working. My application crashes and saves a dump-file, but my debugging skills are quite limited so I'm not sure what is causing the crash. The code that I have that I believe is causing the crash looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "flames.h"
#include "fmodel.h"
typedef struct row_tag
{
    int index;
    double *data;
} row_t; 
size_t get_col_count(FILE *is)
{

    size_t col_count = 1;

    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(is)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
    if (ch == ',')
        ++col_count;

    rewind(is);
    return col_count;
}

row_t* csv_read(FILE *is, size_t *cols, size_t *rows)
{
    *cols = get_col_count(is);
    *rows = 0;
    char const *origin_format = "%*[^ ,]%c";
    char const *row_header_format = "%d%c";
    char const *format = "%lf%c";
    row_t *csv = NULL;

    bool valid = true;
    for (size_t current_row = 0; valid; ++current_row)  {
        csv = (row_t*)realloc(csv, (current_row + 1)* sizeof(row_t));
        csv[current_row].data = (double*)calloc((size_t)cols - 1, sizeof(double));

        for (size_t current_col = 0; valid && current_col < (size_t)cols; ++current_col)    {

            char delim;
            if (!current_col && !current_row) {
                if (fscanf(is, origin_format, &delim) != 1 || delim != ',') {
                    valid = false;
                    //continue;
                }
                csv[0].index = -1;
            }
            else if (!current_col) {
                int result = -1;
                if ((result = fscanf(is, row_header_format, &csv[current_row].index, &delim)) != 2 || delim != ',') {
                    valid = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (fscanf(is, format, &csv[current_row].data[current_col - 1], &delim) != 2 || delim != ',' && delim != '\n')
                    valid = false;
            }
        }
        if (!valid)
            free(csv[current_row].data);
        else *rows = current_row + 1;
    }
    return csv;
}

void csv_free(row_t *csv, size_t rows)
{
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
        free(csv[row].data);
    free(csv);
}

double csv_get_value(row_t *csv, int col_index, size_t cols, int row_index, size_t rows)
{
    size_t col;
    for (col = 1; csv[0].data[col] != col_index && col < cols; ++col);
    if (col >= cols || csv[0].data[col] != col_index)
        return 0.;

    size_t row;
    for (row = 1; csv[row].index != row_index && row < rows; ++row);
    if (row >= rows || csv[row].index != row_index)
        return 0.;

    return csv[row].data[col];
}
```

And then in my main function: (note that FMHPrint is just a printing function in the application I'm working in called FLAMES, therefore the includes aswell)

```
char const *filename = "Dampening.csv";
      FILE *is = fopen(filename, "r");
      if (!is) {
          FMHPrint(0, 0, "Couldnt open \%s\ for reading!\n\n", filename);
          return (FFAILURE);
      }

      size_t cols;
      size_t rows;
      row_t *csv = csv_read(is, &cols, &rows);
      FMHPrint(0, 0, "Cols: %zu\n", cols);
      FMHPrint(0, 0, "Rows: %zu\n", rows);

      fclose(is);

      for (size_t y = 0; y < rows; ++y) {
          printf("%2d: ", csv[y].index);
          for (size_t x = 0; x < cols - 1; ++x)
              printf("%f ", csv[y].data[x]);
          putchar('\n');
      }

      double value = csv_get_value(csv, 550, cols, 7, rows);
      FMHPrint(0, 0, "Dampening value is: %f", value);

      csv_free(csv, rows);
```

I have no idea why FLAMES keeps crashing, and the DMP-file isn't very helpful for me. Can anyone explain what is wrong? :)
Regards, Anders

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe alongside writing your master thesis you should check out a debugging tool too to help you out in situations like these, instead of relying on so for on demand debugging services.

Comment: For what it's worth, this looks overly complicated to me for what it's doing. I would do this with a simple state machine, processing one character at a time (at the beginning of a field, within a field, at end of field, at end of line, and so on).

Comment: *"I have no idea why..."* - run your program built with debug symbols and fed the secret input file Dampening.csv under a *debugger*. If it predictably, repeatedly crashes, you'll find out right-quick where.

Comment: You pass in `rows` and `cols` as pointers, so that cou can update the variables in `main`. When you use these to dimension your allocations, you must dereference them, not cast the pointer values to `size_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `cols` and `rows` as pointer to the reading function, so that you can update the variables in the calling function. When you allocate memory for each row:

```
csv[current_row].data = (double*)calloc((size_t)cols - 1, sizeof(double));
```

you use `cols`, which is a pointer. You probably got a compiler warning, so you decided to cast the value to `size_t`, but that doesn't solve the problem, it only makes the warning go away.

The value you want is where the pointer points to, so you must dereference it:

```
csv[current_row].data = calloc(*cols - 1, sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the help. But when I do that, the "=" gives me an error saying "A value of type 'void*' cannot be assigned to an entity of type 'double*'"
That's why I did the type casting :/

Comment: Oh, that's another problem. I've removed the cast to `(double *)`for the result of `calloc`, because in C, you don't need it. Perhaps you are using a C++ compiler (or something that you're not aware of is a C++ compiler under the hood), which would require the cast. If you compiler complains, put that back in. The actual error was using `(size_t) cols` instead of `*cols`. For what it's worth, I compiled your program and run it on a 1000x1000 csv file I created. The fix above fixes your problem, I think.

Comment: Hmm, tried that and that compiles, and now it's another crash haha... 
When my program crashes it gives me an error message:
"Debug Error! HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#76) at 0x00000188A26E46A0
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

(press retry to debug the application)"

Comment: @AndersHamfeldt: The same "casting the compiler silent" issue here: `for (size_t current_col = 0; valid && current_col < (size_t)cols; ++current_col)`

Comment: Seems to be working now. Thank you for all the help, much appreciated! :D